# Click on “Show more deals” in webpage with Python Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the following code to click on the 'Show more reviews' button, but not working.

Code:

```
link= 'https://www.capterra.com/p/5938/Oracle-Database/'
driver.get(link)
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Show more reviews').click()
        # Wait till the container of the recipes gets loaded 
        # after load more is clicked.
        time.sleep(5)
    except (NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException) as e:
        break

page_source = driver.page_source

#BEAUTIFUL SOUP OPTION
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"lxml")
```

Error Statement

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Show more reviews"}
(Session info: headless chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why While True??

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to it.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Show more reviews"]').click()`

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48673343/6486100
Thanks @Andersson